# How to make nested loop faster to find instr in vba

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

**Problem Description:** Loop through excel max rows(approx. 10000000) to find instr. After finding instr, taking the values and copy the values to different sheet. Every time find the match which is instr, copy the value only the matches and paste it to different sheet.

**Problem:** I am using nested loop and my loop is running slow, so for 10 millions rows its taking around 19:37 mins. I timed it. So first question is there different ways of doing it or how do i make it faster instead of 20 mins, is it possible to compare 20 millions( each sheet 10 million rows, 10 million strings) strings within 1 min or two. Here is my current code

```
  Sub zym()
   Dim x As Long, lastrow As Long, lastrowx As Long, i As Long, ii As Long
   Dim ws As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, b As String
   Dim j As Long

   Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
   Set ws2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")
   Set ws3 = Worksheets("Sheet3")
   j = 1
      T1 = GetTickCount

  lastrow = ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1
  lastrowx = ws2.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1

   ReDim sheet1array(1 To lastrow)
   ReDim sheet2array(1 To lastrowx)

    For i = LBound(sheet1array) To UBound(sheet1array)
        b = "-" & ws.Range("A" & i) & "-"
      For ii = LBound(sheet2array) To UBound(sheet2array)
        If InStr(1, ws2.Range("A" & ii), b) > 0 Then
        ws3.Range("A" & j) = ws2.Range("A" & ii)
        j = j + 1
        End If

       Next ii
     Next i
    Debug.Print "Array Time = " & (GetTickCount - T1) / 1000#
    Debug.Print "Array Count = " & Format(ii, "#,###")

End Sub
```

Comment: You are not comparing 20 million strings. You are comparing 10,000,000*10,000,000 = 100 trillion strings. While I'm sure optimizations could be made, the expectation of getting this down to one minute is simply unrealistic. Is there a reason you don't break out of the inner loop once a match is found?

Comment: @Kyle 19:37 mins for 100 Trillion strings? I'd be happy with that ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Power Query Add-In for this. It has a Text.Contains function that is roughly similar to VB's InStr. I had a go at this particular challenge and got it working. You can download and use my demo file from my OneDrive:

http://1drv.ms/1AzPAZp

It's the file: Power Query demo - Searching for a list of strings among another list of strings.xlsx.

As described on the ReadMe sheet, I didn't have to write many functions - it was mostly built by clicking around the UI.

My design is to cross-join the Search and Target tables (the equivalent of your Sheet1 and Sheet2 I think) to get every possibly combination, then apply the Text.Contains function and filter on the result.

A key design objective is speed - it runs in about 1 second for the current semi-random test data:
19 Search Strings (currently single words)
78780 Target Strings (currently lines from War and Peace)
(so around 1.5 million combinations)
9268 Output matches.

So non-trivial scale, but nowhere near your requirements. Hopefully that will scale up to your needs - I'm keen to hear how it goes.

Note that the Target_Strings query could be replaced with one querying data directly from a database or website - Power Query is not limited to Excel as a datasource.

Answer (score 0):

Reading from and writing to cells on a sheet slows down any macro. The following code copies cell values into arrays and loops through these. Output is copied in chunks from a result array into the target sheet.
On my notebook the original code took 56 sec, this code 3.7 sec:

```
Sub zym2()
    Dim lastrow As Long, i As Long, j As Long, start As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, ws3 As Worksheet
    Dim b As String
    Dim T1 As Long
    Dim arr1, arr2, arr3, c

    Set ws = Worksheets("sh1")
    Set ws2 = Worksheets("sh2")
    Set ws3 = Worksheets("sh3")
    ws3.Columns(1).Clear
    T1 = Timer

    arr1 = Intersect(ws.Columns(1), ws.UsedRange)
    lastrow = UBound(arr1)
    arr2 = ws2.UsedRange
    ReDim arr3(1 To lastrow / 10, 2)   ' initial length is arbitrary

    j = 0
    start = 1
    For i = 1 To lastrow
        b = "-" & arr1(i, 1) & "-"
        For Each c In arr2
            If InStr(1, c, b) > 0 Then
                If j = UBound(arr3) Then
                    ws3.Range(Cells(start, 1), Cells(start - 1 + j, 1)) = arr3
                    start = start + j
                    j = 0
                End If
                j = j + 1
                arr3(j, 1) = c
            End If
        Next c
    Next i
    If j > 0 Then
        ws3.Range(Cells(start, 1), Cells(start - 1 + j, 1)) = arr3
    End If
    Debug.Print "Array Time = " & Format(Timer - T1, "##.0")
    Debug.Print "Array Count = " & Format(start - 1 + j, "#,###")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I have already offered an answer I want to propose a totally different algorithm here in order to improve the performance by another order of magnitude.
When the "big list" on sheet1 is scanned and matches in sheet2 are searched, the information about a successful search is thrown away after one pass. Sheet1 will contain repetitions of a search value, and when scanning sheet2 we can make use of it's frequency.

The means to finding unique search values and their frequencies is a dictionary object. To use it in VBA one has to add a reference to "Microsoft Scripting" in the VBA editor.
The second assumption is that the output list does not need to preserve the input order (because it will be sorted anyway). The following code will produce an output list in sheet3 with search values in the order in which they occur in the big list but with all repetitions in one block. Statements for timing have been commented out as an external class definition is needed for this.

```
Sub zym_dict()
' http://superuser.com/questions/976906/how-to-make-nested-loop-faster-to-find-instr-in-vba
' by E/S/P 2015-09-25
' 2nd improvement: use a dictionary object to count unique search items and loop over these
' speed 1:13 vs. array version; 1:186 vs. original (cell) version

    Dim numvalues As Long, i As Long, j As Long, nextresult As Long
    Dim numcompared As Long, numresults As Long
    Dim cnt As Long
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, ws3 As Worksheet
    Dim searchterm As String
    Dim values, arr2, results, c, v
    Dim uniq As New Scripting.Dictionary

    ' Dim mStopWatch As New clsStopWatch

    Set ws1 = Worksheets("sheet1")
    Set ws2 = Worksheets("sheet2")
    Set ws3 = Worksheets("sheet3")

    ' mStopWatch.StartWatch

    values = Intersect(ws1.Columns(1), ws1.UsedRange)
    arr2 = Intersect(ws2.Range("A:B"), ws2.UsedRange)
    numcompared = UBound(arr2, 1)

    ' collect unique values and their frequencies
    For i = 1 To UBound(values, 1)
        uniq(values(i, 1)) = uniq(values(i, 1)) + 1
    Next i

    numresults = 0
    ' 2nd index is repeat count
    For j = 1 To numcompared
        arr2(j, 2) = 0
    Next j

    For Each v In uniq
        searchterm = "-" & v & "-"
        cnt = uniq.Item(v)
        For j = 1 To numcompared
            If InStr(1, arr2(j, 1), searchterm) > 0 Then
                ' copy this value multiple times into result array
                arr2(j, 2) = arr2(j, 2) + cnt ' repeat count
                numresults = numresults + cnt
            End If
        Next j
    Next

    ' generate output list
    ReDim results(1 To numresults, 1 To 2)
    ws3.Columns(1).Clear
    nextresult = 0
    For i = 1 To numcompared
        v = arr2(i, 1)
        cnt = arr2(i, 2)  ' may be 0!
        For j = 1 To cnt
            results(nextresult + j, 1) = v
        Next j
        nextresult = nextresult + cnt
    Next i

    ' copy values to sheet
    ws3.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(nextresult, 2)) = results

    ' Debug.Print "runtime = " & Format(mStopWatch.StopWatch, "#0.00 ms")
    Debug.Print Format(nextresult, "#,### resulting lines")
End Sub
```

Compared to the OP's code the speed improvement is 1:186. A 20 minute run would then only take a couple of seconds.